# How to use the relationship with BelongsToMany in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-relations

I'm having trouble how to use the `belongsToMany` method of Laravel to create a relationship. I don't fully understand the description of the parameters. I have the following situation:

Fields of table `products`:

- `id`
- ...
- `product_unique_identifier`

Fields of table `product_images`:

- `id`
- `app_image_id`
- `product_unique_identifier`

Fields of table `app_images`:

- `id`
- ...

Now as you can imagine, I want to use in my `Product` model as well as in my `AppImage` model a relationship to the other table using the `product_images` table. The thing is, that the column `product_unique_identifier` is not the identity field in the `products` table, but a field of type `string`.

One product can have multiple images - one image is always related to one product.

I already tried this in my `AppImage` model:

```
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Product\Product::class, 'product_images','app_image_id','product_unique_key','id','product_unique_key');
}
```

This is not working as expected. I already had a look into the Laravel framework code (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php), but the explanations of the parameters is still not clear to me (which are pivot and related fields as described in the comments of the properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Product\Product::class, 'product_images','app_image_id','product_unique_identifier');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can define the relationship using the belongsToMany method as follows:

In Product model:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(AppImage::class, 'product_images', 'product_unique_identifier', 'app_image_id');
}
```

In AppImage model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_images', 'app_image_id', 'product_unique_identifier');
}
```